# GeoServer ImageMosaic OpenLayers strange layer duplication at Scale = 1 : 34K

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, image-mosaic

I have made a simple ImageMosaic out of 2x GeoTIFF (+ .ovr +.msk for each).

In the map preview at Scale = 1 : 34K, the TIFFs are duplicating as per the image.

This only happens at this zoom level. Does not occur at any other zoom level.

How can I fix this / prevent this from happening?

I cannot share the files as they are over 25mb

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file. It would also be useful to know what the `gdalinfo`  on one of the images is